# MapInfo Thematic Mapping - All other values?

Tags: mapinfo, thematic-map

Relatively quick question here, how do I go about adding a style for all other values using individual value thematic mapping in MapInfo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you get to the "Create Thematic Map - Step 3 of 3 Window", click the "Legend.." button.  You will be shown the "Customize Legend" box - on the right handside of which is the range labels list, including at the bottom "all others" - highlight this row and below there is a check box for "Show the Range" - check it and that should be it

[image: screen shot showing the SHow All Others for the thematic set up]

Comment: Thanks, it shows it on the legend but does not let me choose a style for it :S